# Mysql: Subtract one column's data from another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to subtract one column of data from another, namely `gdded` from `gppy`; both are stored in a MySQL database.

Here is my code but it seems there is something wrong. I've searched anywhere but I cannot find the right answer.

My script below

```
INSERT INTO denmrk 
(EMPID, NAME, DATE_FR, DATE_TO, Tangkay, Alis, gppy, gdded , NET_PAY, SSS_comboE, IBG_EMPLYE, PROCESSED_DATE)
VALUES
(6666, 'JUAN DELACRUZ', '2014-02-01 00:00:00', '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'BBBB CO', 'DRIVER', 3383.04, 300, gppy- gdded , 150, 150, GETDATE() );
```

With the given code and implied database structure, how can I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *substract*. Do you want to receive a timespan? Have a look at the `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: Nope. Just wanted to subtract 3383.04 which is the gppy and the gdded which is 300.

Comment: just use 3383.04 - 300, cause you not yet insert the data into db. I believe those value should be get from variable right?

Comment: I followed the insertion first advice then use this to update.       `UPDATE TRANS set NET_PAY =  (3383.04 - 300)  where EMPID = 6666` and still go error which says [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '3383.04'.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the wrong columns...

Comment: once you inserted into db, you can use this directly UPDATE TRANS set NET_PAY =  gppy- gdded   where EMPID = 6666

Comment: This shows up everytime I tried this one.     `[SQL] UPDATE TRANS set NET_PAY = gppy - gdded where EMPID = 6666

[Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gppy'.
42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gdded'.
`

Comment: your table name is : denmrk, not TRANS, trans is a transaction UPDATE denmrk set NET_PAY = gppy- gdded where EMPID = 6666

Comment: Now this shows up,`[Err] 22018 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CUARTEROS,' to data type int.`

Comment: @avisheks did u downvote me? Nice as you can notice I put mysql in my title because im using mysql and im asking with regards to mysql not mssql. I reported this case to admins since you downvote without properly asking.

Comment: @Dodgeball, well wait, I didn't down vote.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Where are the values *3383.04* and *300* coming from. There, where you add these two values to your query you have to add the substraction result, as well.

Comment: @Dodgeball, Now this shows up,[Err] 22018 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CUARTEROS,' to data type int. this is because in your column either gppy or gdded contains wrong data, datatype for this column suppose to be float or double, check again your table having valid data or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW there is no need to store the manipulated result in the database. You can do this when you are select the data from the database. SO it would be better to drop that col and the idea to store the calc result in the database as well.

Comment: Error shows up `[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: I agree with that. Why should one want to store a substraction result of two columns of the same dataset?